# Why does Chrome occasionally show the referrer URL after you hover off of a link?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Chrome has been really irritating me lately with the URL hover feature. I'll hover over a normal link, and then unhover. You would think that the URL preview in the bottom left corner would go away, but it doesn't. Instead, it shows the referrer URL (from the header), and it had me thinking that I had bad links. Is this a strange glitch or supposed to happen?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: The version of Chrome and operating system would be useful.

Comment: Chrome 9.0.597.84 on OSX 10.6.

Comment: That does not sound like something endemic to Chrome itself. It really sounds like something is performing some sort of third-party processing of your hyperlinks. Do you have any extensions or plugins installed?